# Is there a way to create a table in phmyadmin using a select statement?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with a lot of data. I want to create multiple tables from this large data set. I know how to select the attributes I need using a select statement, it would be really convenient to create a table from that select statement. Something like "select * from mytable as e where ID=blahblah; create table from e;".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM old_table
WHERE blah blah blah
```

This isn't just for phpMyAdmin, it's a standard SQL query that can be used anywhere.

Comment: The WHERE clause would contain typical filters, e.g., WHERE uid = '$userid', etc. right?

Comment: that seems simple and intuitive thanks, giving it a try.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Of course. _blah blah blah_ is just a placeholder for whatever he would normally put there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table in the same vein you would a query.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html for more information on CREATE TABLE syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
CREATE TABLE tblnew SELECT * FROM othertable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to maintain the data as it changes, a better approach might be to create views of the table that filter records by blahblah. That way the data is only stored once and can be updated, deleted and added to more easily. It's as simple as:
CREATE VIEW myview AS select_statement;

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html.